# HTML circle image gradually gets smaller over 1 minute

Tags: html, time, size, shapes

Im looking to have a large circle on a webpage that gradually gets smaller over 60 seconds, then triggers some text and then gets larger again in HTML, though sadly my HTML isn't very good.

I realize i could use a loop for this and make the shape smaller each loop though if i do it that way how can i make the loop run for exactly 60 seconds?

if anyone can point me in the right direction i would be very very grateful.

Comment: Use javascript. More precisely jQuery. you don't need to know advanced programming, it's very easy if you follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript for this since it cannot be done using pure Html.

You can use the setInterval function in javascript to run a function every 1s and do whatever you want in that function. Sample below.

```
mainFunction(){
  setInterval(doSomething, 1000); //here 1000 means 1000ms ie it will run every 1s
}

doSomething(){
   //here you can change the radius of your circle to make it grow bigger/smaller every 1s
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your fast reply - i will try that now

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is the answer if you don't know much about it. It has functions to make animations like the one you want to make. [In this page](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) you'll find all you need, but I'm gonna put a snippet here to make you see what you can do within a few minutes:

```js
var x = 10;
$("#try").on('click', function(){
  x = 10;
  animate1();
});

function animate1(){
  console.log(x);
  if (x > 0){
  x = x - 1;
  $("#text").html("Small text");
  $("#text").animate({fontSize: '40'}, 1000, "swing", animate2);
  
  }
};
function animate2(){
  if (x > 0){
  x = x - 1;
  $("#text").html("Big text");
  $("#text").animate({fontSize: '10'}, 1000, "swing", animate1);
  
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Small text</div>
<br>
<button id="try">Try this!</button>
```

Comment: this looks good - i copped the code into my project and started to play with it though couldn't get it to work yet. the device im deploying the finished item too needs to run offline. if i copy the code from the page you link and save it in the directory of the project would this work? e.g. '<script src="js\jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: I guess it should, but otherwise put it in the HTML code

Comment: oh you meant the jquery file, yes, it must work that way too